# Не стартует Activity в приложении

Tags: java, android

Задачу поставил реализовать выбор года, месяца и числа не средствами библиотек, а от руки. В чем я ошибаюсь?

Лог ошибки

> 08-10 19:59:13.906 21295-21295/game.life.ru.basicviews
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: game.life.ru.basicviews, PID: 21295
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{game.life.ru.basicviews/game.life.ru.basicviews.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:
>   "android.widget.NumberPicker{1f23bb19 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0
>   #7f0b0056 app:id/numberPicker3}"
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:
>   "android.widget.NumberPicker{1f23bb19 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0
>   #7f0b0056 app:id/numberPicker3}"
>                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
>                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
>                                                                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
>                                                                                at game.life.ru.basicviews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2273)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Код программы

```
package game.life.ru.basicviews;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public NumberPicker yearChoose ;
    public NumberPicker monthChoose ;
    public int maxDay = 31;
    public int maxYear = 2016;
    public int minYear = 1940;
    public int maxMonth = 12;
    public int minMonth = 1;
    public int minDay = 1;
    public String yearChoseStr = "";
    public int yearChoseInt = 0;
    public String monthChoseStr = "";
    public int monthChoseInt = 0;
    public int modif = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NumberPicker numberPicker3 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);
        numberPicker3.setMaxValue(maxYear);
        numberPicker3.setMinValue(minYear);
        yearChoose = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);

        yearChoseStr = yearChoose.toString();
        yearChoseInt = Integer.parseInt(yearChoseStr);

        if(yearChoseInt%4==0 && yearChoseInt%100 !=0 || yearChoseInt%400==0){//проверка высокосности года
            modif = modif+1;
        }
        else {
            modif = 0;
        }
        NumberPicker numberPicker2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
        numberPicker2.setMaxValue(maxMonth);
        numberPicker2.setMinValue(minMonth);
        monthChoose = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);

        monthChoseStr = monthChoose.toString();
        monthChoseInt = Integer.parseInt(monthChoseStr);

        switch (yearChoseInt)
        {
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 12:
                maxDay = 31;
                break;
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
                maxDay = 30;
                break;
            case 2:
            default:
                maxDay = 28 + modif;
        }


        NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(maxDay);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(minDay);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Давайте читать стектрейс.

`java.lang.NumberFormatException` говорит нам о том, что вы пытаетесь преобразовать в число строку, не являющуюся представлением числа. И нам сообщают как конкретно выглядела эта строка:

```
Invalid int: "android.widget.NumberPicker{1f23bb19 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0056 app:id/numberPicker3}"
```

Тут становится очевидным, что был вызван метод `toString()` на объекте класса `NumberPicker`. Дальше мы узнаем, где это произошло:

```
at game.life.ru.basicviews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
```

на 31й строке в файле `MainActivity.java`, в методе `onCreate` класса `MainActivity`.

И действительно, там мы видим следующее:

```
yearChoose = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);

yearChoseStr = yearChoose.toString();
yearChoseInt = Integer.parseInt(yearChoseStr);
```

Вы получаете объект `NumberPicker` и зачем-то вызываете на нем `.toString()`, в то время как у него есть метод [`getValue()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#getValue()), который сразу вернет вам число, введеное пользователем.